# How to change the border colors according to time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the color of the borders when its open up until its close. for Example: it opens at 10am and it border is green up until 9:29pm then it turns yellow from 9:30pm to 9:44pm then it turns orange from 9:45pm until close time at 10pm. The problem i have encounter is the colors turn at 11:29pm to 11:44 yellow and so on until twelve the red. My question is. am i placing the else right or equalling the hours and minutes

```js
var imgArray = new Array();

imgArray[0] = new Image();
imgArray[0].src = 'http://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/1/1/3/4/11341626/custom_themes/599346900698327146/files/Gifs/OpenLightOff.png';

imgArray[1] = new Image();
imgArray[1].src = 'http://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/1/1/3/4/11341626/custom_themes/599346900698327146/files/Gifs/OpenLightOn.gif';




var now = new Date();
var weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0] = "Sunday";
weekday[1] = "Monday";
weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
weekday[4] = "Thursday";
weekday[5] = "Friday";
weekday[6] = "Saturday";

var today = weekday[now.getDay()];
var dayOfWeek = now.getDay();


var checkTime3 = function() {

  var timeBorder3 = document.getElementById('timeBorder3');
  var timeDiv3 = document.getElementById('timeDiv3');

  var hour = now.getHours();
  var minutes = now.getMinutes();
  var suffix = hour >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";  //add AM or PM

  
  // add 0 to one digit minutes
  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes
  };


  if (dayOfWeek == 0 || dayOfWeek == 1 || dayOfWeek == 2 || dayOfWeek == 3 || dayOfWeek == 4 ) {
    //Open Greeen:Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday
       if ((dayOfWeek == 0 || dayOfWeek == 1 || dayOfWeek == 2 || dayOfWeek == 3 || dayOfWeek == 4 ) && hour > 9 && (hour > 21 == minutes < 30)) {
    hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1); //i.e. show 1:15 instead of 13:15
 timeBorder3.className = 'OpenGreen';
    timeDiv3.innerHTML = 'it\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + '<br><center><img style="width:100%;top:0px;border-radius:10px;" src='+imgArray[1].src+'></center>';
    timeDiv3.className = 'open';

  }
      //Open Yellow:Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday
     else if ((dayOfWeek == 0 || dayOfWeek == 1 || dayOfWeek == 2 || dayOfWeek == 3 || dayOfWeek == 4 ) && hour > 9 && (hour > 21 == minutes < 45)) {
    hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1); //i.e. show 1:15 instead of 13:15
 timeBorder3.className = 'OpenYellow';
    timeDiv3.innerHTML = 'it\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + '<br><center><img style="width:100%;top:0px;border-radius:10px;" src='+imgArray[1].src+'></center>';
    timeDiv3.className = 'openYellow';
  } 
       //Open Orange:Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday
     else if ((dayOfWeek == 0 || dayOfWeek == 1 || dayOfWeek == 2 || dayOfWeek == 3 || dayOfWeek == 4 ) && hour > 9 && (hour > 21 == minutes < 60))  {
    hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1); //i.e. show 1:15 instead of 13:15
 timeBorder3.className = 'OpenOrange';
    timeDiv3.innerHTML = 'it\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + '<br><center><img style="width:100%;top:0px;border-radius:10px;" src='+imgArray[1].src+'></center>';
    timeDiv3.className = 'openOrange';
  }
     //Closed
     else {
    if (hour == 0 || hour > 10 ) {
      hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1); //i.e. show 1:15 instead of 13:15
    }
 timeBorder3.className = 'closedRed';
    timeDiv3.innerHTML = 'It\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + '<br><center><img style="width:100%;top:0px;border-radius:10px;" src='+imgArray[0].src+'></center>';
    timeDiv3.className = 'closed';
  }
  
  }
  //Open Green: Friday And Saturday
  else if ((dayOfWeek == 5 || dayOfWeek == 6) && hour > 9 || (hour > 22 == minutes < 30)) {
    hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1);
 timeBorder3.className = 'OpenGreen';
    timeDiv3.innerHTML = 'it\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + '<br><center><img style="width:100%;top:0px;border-radius:10px;" src='+imgArray[1].src+'></center>';
    timeDiv3.className = 'open';
  }
  //Open Yellow: Friday And Saturday
  else if ((dayOfWeek == 5 || dayOfWeek == 6) && hour > 9 || (hour > 22 == minutes < 45)) {
    hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1);
 timeBorder3.className = 'OpenYellow';
    timeDiv3.innerHTML = 'it\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + '<br><center><img style="width:100%;top:0px;border-radius:10px;" src='+imgArray[1].src+'></center>';
    timeDiv3.className = 'openYellow';
  }
 //Open Orange: Friday And Saturday
  else if ((dayOfWeek == 5 || dayOfWeek == 6) && hour > 9 || (hour > 22 == minutes < 59)) {
    hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1);
 timeBorder3.className = 'OpenOrange';
    timeDiv3.innerHTML = 'it\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + '<br><center><img style="width:100%;top:0px;border-radius:10px;" src='+imgArray[1].src+'></center>';
    timeDiv3.className = 'openOrange';
  }
 
  //Closed
  else {
    if (hour == 0 || hour > 10) {
      hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1); //i.e. show 1:15 instead of 13:15
    }
 timeBorder3.className = 'closedRed';
    timeDiv3.innerHTML = 'It\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + '<br><center><img style="width:100%;top:0px;border-radius:10px;" src='+imgArray[0].src+'></center>';
    timeDiv3.className = 'closed';
  }
  
  };
$(function() {
checkTime3();
});
```

```css
/*timee*/



/*Borer of DIV Green*/
.OpenGreen {
  position:relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 4px #3DFF01;
  animation: Open 1s infinite;
}
@keyframes Open {
 50%{box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 4px #30cc00;}
}


/*Font Color Yellow*/
.openYellow {
  position:relative;
  color:yellow;

}

/*Border Of DIV Yellow*/
.OpenYellow {
  position:relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 4px #ffff00;
  animation: openYellow 1s infinite;
}
@keyframes openYellow {
 50%{box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 4px #FFE700;}
}

/*Font Color Orange*/
.openOrange {
  position:relative;
  color:#ff6700;

}

/*Border Of DIV Orange*/
.OpenOrange {
  position:relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 4px #ff6700;
  animation: openOrange 1s infinite;
}
@keyframes openOrange {
 50%{box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 4px #FF5A00;}
}


/*Font Color Red*/
.closed {

  color: rgba(231, 76, 60, 0.85);

}

/*Border Of DIV Red*/
.closedRed {
position:relative;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 4px #FF0101;
animation: close 1s infinite;
}
@keyframes close {
 50%{box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 4px #e50000;}
}

[id^="timeBorder"] {
 border-radius:20px;
 margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
 margin-top:8px;
 bottom:5px;
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 padding:0px;
    width:182px;
 height:182px;
 z-index:1;
 overflow:hidden;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
 
 [id ^="timeDiv"]
 {


  width:100%;
  background: transparent;
  margin: 0 auto;

  border-radius: 3px;

 /* -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 16px -8px #adadad;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 16px -8px #adadad;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px -8px #adadad;*/
  display:block;

  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/*time end*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="timeBorder3"><center><div id="timeDiv3"></div></center></div>
```

Comment: Use jQuery `setInterval` function to do this and set border color within that by generating random color...

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is here :

```
(hour > 22 == minutes < 59)
```

I don't know if there is syntax like that.

How can hour > 22 can be equal minutes < 59 ?

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: what im tried to tell it is that they are both of the same but diffrent. if i added || or && it would have said 9pm to 12 or how would u represent from 10am to 9:30pm green and 9:31 to 9:44pm yellow then 9:45pm to 9:59pm orange then at 10 red for close

Comment: You have to use AND ( &&) because PHP can not understand your approach

Answer (score 0):

Ahmet Karabulut is right.

Instead of `if ((dayOfWeek == 0 || dayOfWeek == 1 || dayOfWeek == 2 || dayOfWeek == 3 || dayOfWeek == 4 ) && hour > 9 && (hour > 21 == minutes < 30))` you should use this `if (dayOfWeek >= 0 && dayOfWeek <= 4 && (hour > 22 && minutes < 59))`

I corrected my previous answer.

EDIT 1:

Something like this:

```
if (hour >= 9 && hour <= 23 && dayOfWeek >= 0 && dayOfWeek <= 4) {
  //make Stuff green
}else if (hour == 23 && dayOfWeek >= 0 && dayOfWeek <= 4) {
  if (minutes >= 45) {
    //make stuff Orange
  }else if (minutes >= 30) {
    //make stuff yellow
  }else {
  // make stuff red
}
```

Comment: what im tried to tell it is that they are both of the same but diffrent. if i added || or && it would have said 9pm to 12 or how would u represent from 10am to 9:30pm green and 9:31 to 9:44pm yellow then 9:45pm to 9:59pm orange then at 10 red for close meaning this if (dayOfWeek >= 0 && dayOfWeek <= 4 && hour > 9 && (hour > 22 && minutes < 59))

Comment: It still doesn't change colors at the appropriate minute set

Comment: //Friday - Saturday
  else if(hour >= 6 && hour <= 23 && dayOfWeek >= 5 && dayOfWeek <= 6){
      //Turn Border Green
   if (hour >= 23 == minutes <= 29){
 hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1); //i.e. show 1:15 instead of 13:15

  }
      else if (hour == 23) {
 //Turn Border Orange
 if (minutes >= 45) {
 hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1); //i.e. show 1:15 instead of 13:15

  }
   //Turn Border Yellow
    else if (minutes >= 30) {
 hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1); //i.e. show 1:15 instead of 13:15

  }
        

  }